# Заполнить массив значениями из базы данных и получить их кол-во

Tags: c#

я получаю из базы данных строку следующего типа 
1,2,3,4,5
Мне нужно заполнить массив int этими значениями и посчитать их кол-во (в данном случае 5)
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: заполнить массив int этими значениями и посчитать их кол-во. или за вас код написать?

Comment: @biggiemot Код можете написать, пожалуйста?

Comment: для начала приложите кусок кода получения данных из БД

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5";

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
    return;

int[] arr = str.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();

//arr.Dump();
foreach (var element in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Размер массива: {arr.Length}");
```

Подразумевается, что строка является строкой правильного формата и все числа могут быть приведены к int

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]